# Pandas giving error to read txt data file

Tags: python, pandas

This is the code that I am using and it is not working for some reason. Please help me out.

I have created a text file with some data and when I try to use Pandas to read the data it is not working.

```
dF = pd.read_csv("PandasLongSample.txt", delimiter='/t')
print(dF)
```

This is the error:

```
C:\Users\SVISHWANATH\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:1: ParserWarning: Falling back to the 'python' engine because the 'c' engine does not support regex separators (separators > 1 char and different from '\s+' are interpreted as regex); you can avoid this warning by specifying engine='python'.
  """Entry point for launching an IPython kernel.
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a backslash (\) instead of a slash (/) for the tab delimiter.

```
dF = pd.read_csv("PandasLongSample.txt", delimiter='\t')
print(dF)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in your code, it should be `\t` instead of `/t`